# Connect pyethapp to testrpc - Is there an equivalent to `geth attach` in pyethapp?

Tags: json-rpc, testrpc, python, pyethereum, pyethapp

I have an instance of testrpc running:

```
testrpc -a 1000
```

when using geth, I'd do this:

```
geth attach rpc:http://localhost:8545
```

to link to it.

I have pyethapp installed and would like to do something similar - is this possible?

Looking through the code there is an [`rpc_client.py`](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/blob/1f97f98b332f2a03cb58bd6bc78daa45181a3fb1/pyethapp/rpc_client.py) file that states:

```
""" A simple way of interacting to a ethereum node through JSON RPC commands. """
```

I interpret this as a means to connect to my testrpc simulated node, but I can't figure out which functions to use....

**How do you connect to a testrpc simulated node using pyethapp?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it need to be pyethapp, or are you open to any library that allows you to interact with a client?

One option is to connect using [web3.py](https://github.com/pipermerriam/web3.py), installed with `pip install web3`.

From [the docs](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html), edited for simplicity:

```
>>> from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
>>> web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))
>>> web3.eth.blockNumber
4000000
```